# How to access parent view in android studio using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to access `TextInputLayout` from its child view `PasswordEditText` (my custom view extends from `AppCompatEditText`)

```
val editText = findViewById<PasswordEditText>(R.id.passwordEditText)
val textInputLayout = editText.parent as TextInputLayout
```

But the code above give `java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` error

This is my xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/passwordEditTextLayout"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                android:alpha="0"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_lock_24">

                <com.alifmaulanarizqi.submission1.customview.PasswordEditText
                    android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: val textInputLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.passwordEditTextLayout)

Answer (score 0):

editText.parent basically return framlayout, If you want to get original parent-view you need to write like this..

```
findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.passwordEditTextLayout)
```